# How to turn off the bell sound in ubuntu server?

Tags: 18.04, sound, terminal-bell

Please help, I tried the method mentioned on older questions but they seem to be for GUI machines.

Comment: Please tell us **what** you tried, as well as the actual commands and responses.

Answer (score 1):

In case the sound you mean is not actually a bell (since pure-Terminal installations almost never have something "fancy"), but rather the built-in "PC speaker" (i.e. the annoying beeper), you might want to try the following:

First, unload the `pcspkr` kernel module (`# rmmod pcspkr`). If the sound you want gone is indeed gone, you can permanently blacklist it to prevent it from loading on boot:

```
# echo "blacklist pcspkr" > /etc/modprobe.d/pcspkr.conf
```